# Cakephp, why loadModel does not show the related records?

Tags: cakephp

I am using $this->loadModel('SomeModel');
in controller x for reading model y.

Why do not I see the related records?

```
$this->loadModel('SomeModel');
pr($this->SomeModel->find('all')); 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SomeModel] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [created] => 2013-10-10 19:27:46
                    [updated] => 2013-10-14 18:04:14
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [result_id] => 3
                )
        )
```

Comment: what are the relationships attached to your SomeModel?

Comment: did you set recursive to -1 for this or all models?

Comment: `debug(get_class($this->SomeModel))` probably says why

Comment: The relationships are: user_id and result_id. I don't set any recurisve. public function admin_view($id = null) {
$this->loadModel('SomeModel');
pr($this->SomeModel->find('all'));     
        exit;

Comment: Show us your `$belongsTo`, `$hasMany`, `$hasOne` and `$hasAndBelongsTo` variables in your models. So not just "SomeModel" but the actual model. **Note: put the code in your opening post!** Not in a comment for the sake of readability. Also, is your database set up correctly? Does it match the [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can get the related records if you set recrusive=>2 i.e $this->SomeModel->find('all',array('recursive'=>2))

Comment: Even in this way, the related records are not seen.

Comment: Then they are not properly related.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is that I was working in a plugin! $this->loadModel('PluginName.SomeModel');

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but its not the pretty one. Lets start
First: find AppController.php and add public static variable. Lets call it model. Example:

public static $model;

Then:

in your SomeModelController (that Controller will get the main model) you have to make index() action it will look like this:

```
SomeModelController extends AppController {
  function index(){
    parent::$model = $this->SomeModel->find('all');
  }
}
```

OK so we have out data. Now Lets go to the Controller which will pass data to our view. Lets call it viewController.

```
viewController extends AppController{
  function index(){
    $this->requestAction('array('controller'=>'SomeModelController','action'=>'index')')
    $this->set('model',parent::$model);
  }
}
```

And thats it